# sDNA custom metrics data format

Tags: sdna

I am trying to calculate road network properties while using custom distance metric in sDNA – in my case time which differs in segments depending on availability of public transport.

Initially I have imported a table from Excel (where for different groups of polylines the different formulas of “time” were used) and have tried various number formats in attributes table: short, long, single, double, numeric, etc.

For integral analysis I choose custom distance metric and the attribute column as a “custom metric data field”, but the calculations are always unsuccessful with the following message: “Calculation expected numeric field “…”” not found in data”.

Calculations for the same network with angular distances and Euclidean radiuses work well. Symbology displays custom data field.

Any idea what could wrong in the data?

Comment: It looks I have found the solution! The folder where all files are stored should have no gaps and capital letter in the name...but it is a little strange that the other analysis methods work well even if this requirement is not met. I hope it will be useful for someone :)

Comment: That is indeed odd and shouldn't have happened, which platform were you using (QGIS or ArcGIS) and which format (shapefile or gdb?)

Comment: I was using ArcGIS with shape files.